# How to prove $\cos^4x - \sin^4x - \cos^2x + \sin^2x$ is always $0$?

Tags: trigonometry

So I have a small problem here where I have to prove the following :

> $$\cos^4x - \sin^4x - \cos^2x + \sin^2x = 0 $$

I know that the 2nd part is always $1$, so I need to prove that the first part also equals $1$. So how should I prove it ?

**Edit** : Sorry, the equation itself was wrong. I've edited it.

Comment: The formula in the title of your question does not fit with the formula in the body of the question $$\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x \neq 1$$

Comment: $\sin^2x-\cos^2x\neq\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$

Comment: I need to prove that the equation in the body is equal to 0

Comment: @DeltaWeb, is it in the correct form now? Which sign should be before $\sin^2 x$?

Comment: take $x = \pi/4, \cos x =  \sin x = \sqrt 2/2.$ so you get $\cos^4 x + \sin^4 x = 1/4 + 1/4 = 1/2 \neq 1$

Comment: I $\textit{guess}$ what you want to prove is $\cos^4x-\sin^4x-\cos^2x+\sin^2x=0$, right?

Comment: I've edited the OP

Comment: Use $a^4-b^4=(a^2+b^2)(a^2-b^2)$ and the answer is around the corner.

Comment: Found it thank's !

Comment: It is important that you ask and write your question carefully so that no one will be confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple: it's not even true. Unless $x$ is a very specific value.

Your other statement, that's a different story. You can write down

$$\cos^4 x + \sin^4 x = \cos^4 x + \sin^4 x-2\sin^2 x \cos^2x + 2\sin^2x \cos^2 x =$$
$$= (\cos^2x+\sin^2x)^2-2\sin^2 x \cos^2 x = $$
$$=1-2\sin^2 x \cos^2 x=\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x \underbrace{(1-2\cos^2 x)}_{\neq \pm 1}$$
So not even this is true. Nothing's true here.

---

EDIT:

Now it's obvious.

$$\cos^4 x - \sin^4 x -\cos^2 x +\sin^2 x = $$
$$(\cos^2 x -\sin^2 x )\underbrace{(\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x )}_{1}-\cos^2 x +\sin^2 x = 0$$

Comment: I've edited the OP

Answer (score 1):

One more thing that is not true: '2nd part' is not equal to $1$.
$$\cos^4x+\sin^4x-\cos^2x+\sin^2x=\cos^4x+\sin^4x-\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #F0A]{(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)}$$

Comment: Did you code this box by hand, or is there some special tool which I can use to get such effects in my tex equations?

Comment: @YuriyS click on "edit" on his post and you will see the latex code :)

Comment: @Aegis, I did it already, I just wanted to know if I have to always write this by hand

Comment: Actually, I copied it also from someone else :)

Answer (score 1):

This is true for any x if you take $cos^2x-sin^2x$ common and simplify
$$(cos^2x-sin^2x)(cos^2x+sin^2x-1)$$ where $cos^2x+sin^2x=1$ therfore the expression is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is false in general. Try to plot

$$
y=\cos^4(x)+\sin^4(x)
$$

and you will see that it is far from constant!

Answer (score 0):

> Notice, your statement isn't true. Now we know that:
>
> $$\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$$

So, we can see that:

$$\cos^4(x)+\sin^4(x)-\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)=\cos^4(x)+\sin^4(x)-1$$

Now, prove that $\cos^4(x)+\sin^4(x)=\frac{\cos(4x)+3}{4}$:

$$\cos^4(x)+\sin^4(x)=\frac{\cos(4x)+3}{4}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$4\left(\cos^4(x)+\sin^4(x)\right)=\cos(4x)+3\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Use $\sin^4(x)=\left(\sin^2(x)\right)^2=\left(1-\cos^2(x)\right)^2$:

---

$$4\left(\cos^4(x)+\left(1-\cos^2(x)\right)^2\right)=\cos(4x)+3\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Use $\left(1-\cos^2(x)\right)^2=1-2\cos^2(x)+\cos^4(x)$:

---

$$4\left(\cos^4(x)+1-2\cos^2(x)+\cos^4(x)\right)=\cos(4x)+3\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$4\left(1-2\cos^2(x)+2\cos^4(x)\right)=\cos(4x)+3\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$4-8\cos^2(x)+8\cos^4(x)=\cos(4x)+3\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Use $\cos(4x)=\cos(2(2x))=2\cos^2(2x)-1$:

---

$$4-8\cos^2(x)+8\cos^4(x)=2\cos^2(2x)-1+3\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$4-8\cos^2(x)+8\cos^4(x)=2\cos^2(2x)+2\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Use $\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1$:

---

$$4-8\cos^2(x)+8\cos^4(x)=2\left(2\cos^2(x)-1\right)^2+2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$4-8\cos^2(x)+8\cos^4(x)=4-8\cos^2(x)+8\cos^4(x)$$

So:

$$\color{red}{\cos^4(x)+\sin^4(x)-\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)=\frac{\cos(4x)+3}{4}-1=\frac{\cos(4x)-1}{4}\ne0}$$

Answer (score 0):

The edited identity is correct.

Use $a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$ to rewrite $\cos^4 x - \sin^4 x = (\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x)(cos^2 x + \sin^2 x)$.

The second factor is one ($\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$), reducing the original expression to:

$\cos^2x - \sin^2x - \cos^2x + \sin^2x = 0$ as required.